# Cannot connect to home DVR over LTE, but can over wifi

Tags: remote-access, cellular

I have a home camera setup where the DVR has remote viewing via port 8000 and 9000.  I have setup port forwarding on the consumer grade cable modem / router combo.  When I am away from the location (not on the LAN) I can connect to the camera system using the provided app plus DDNS on port 8000 only if I'm on Wifi.  If I'm on cellular data the system sometimes does not connect.

This has been verified by 3 different people, on AT&T and Sprint, on iPhone and Android.  No matter where the person is, if they turn on wifi they can connect to the camera system.

This is not a case of loopback NAT, nobody is connected to the local LAN.  Everybody is accessing the camera system from the public Internet, only sometimes using 4G/LTE technology and sometimes using their own cable/dsl Internet ISP via wifi.

What would cause intermittent connection problems *only over* cellular data?  The device in question does not have a AAAA record, so I don't think it's ipv6 related.  Also, the camera system has been functioning without incident for more than 2 years, only in the past few months has this cellular data issue become a problem.

Comment: I think you are on to something.  I tethered my desktop to my phone and used wireshark.  There is no DNS response for the query.  I've never seen anything like this before.  whatsmydns.net reports all green all around the world, and I am using a 3rd party DDNS service.  Can you promote your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a DNS resolution problem with one particular cell phone carrier.  They would not resolve domains *.dvrlists.com (the ddns provider).